# Finding out the number of special elements in $X$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Let $X=a+\sqrt{-5} b:a, b \in \mathbb Z$. An element $x \in X$ is called special if there exists $y \in X$ such that $xy=1$. Then the question is to find out the number of special elements in $X$

I tried by letting $(a_1+\sqrt 5 ib_1)(a_2+\sqrt 5 ib_2)=1$  which led me to a equation involving four variables. I am unable to proceed further. Any help shall be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(a_1+\sqrt{5}ib_1)(a_2+\sqrt{5}ib_2)=1$ then $|a_1+\sqrt{5}ib_1|^2|a_2+\sqrt{5}ib_2|^2=1$,
that is $(a_1+5b_1^2)(a_2^2+5b_2^2)=1$. Now each of $a_j^2+5b_j^2$
is a nonnegative integer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So that implies $b_j=0$ and $a_j=1, -1$ implying two special elements $1, -1$

Comment: @navinstudent Exactly!